# Error in Wordprewss loop for page template

Tags: loop

This is a page template for custom nivo slider, it gives unexpected endwhile on line 1 error. I can't find out whats wrong.

```
<?php
               /*
Template Name: sliderpage
*/?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="span-24" id="contentwrap">

    <?php //get_sidebars('left'); ?>

    <div class="span-14">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<?php
  $myslider=new WP_query('showposts=5&cat=13');
  //var_dump($myslider);
  if($myslider->have_posts()):
  while ($myslider->have_posts()) : $myslider->the_post(); ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">






 <img src="<?php echo $featured_image_url [0]; ?>" alt="" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
 </a>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_query();
?>
</div>

        <div id="content">  

        </div>

    </div>


<?php get_sidebars('right'); ?>



</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to recreate the error. Maybe it's coming from `<?php get_sidebars('right'); ?>`

I did change your code a little, but it didn't give the *"unexpected endwhile"* error you spoke of. If it's coming from line 1 I'd guess it's the header.php file?

Here is the adjusted code if you want to try it:

```
<?php 
/* 
Template Name: sliderpage */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="span-24" id="contentwrap">
  <div class="span-24" id="contentwrap">
    <div class="span-14">
      <?php
        $myslider=new WP_query('showposts=5&cat=13');
        //var_dump($myslider);
        if($myslider->have_posts()):
        while ($myslider->have_posts()) : $myslider->the_post(); 
        ?>
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="post-image">
            <img src="<?php echo $featured_image_url [0]; ?>" alt="slider-image" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
          </a>        
          <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>          
        </div>

      <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
  <?php get_sidebars('right'); ?>
  </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Your code also used `<?` instead of `<?php`. Short Tags aren't supported in WordPress. Although this isn't the cause of the error it's good to practice proper coding standards.

Comment: Yes it used <? tag which was creating problem, now it works

Comment: I had 2 editors open comparing your code with a slider I use. I must have posted the wrong one (egg on face).

Comment: I just checked my code I don't see the short-tag in there, maybe I need some sleep?

Comment: You are right, i edited code after posting.